# When using ISerializable with DataContractSerializer, how do I stop the serializer from outputting type information?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datacontractserializer, serializable

To get more control over serialization, I have converted a class from `[DataContract]` to `[Serializable]`, implementing both `GetObjectData` and the special deserializing constructor.  When I do this, the XML emitted now has type information applied to all elements.  I don't want this superfluous information, and I'm wondering how to inform the serializer to not output it.

Here's the sample code that uses `[DataContract]`:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
class Test 
{
    public Test() { }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> NullableNumber = 7;
    [DataMember]
    public int Number = 5;

    public static void Go()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
        using (var s = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(s.BaseStream, test);
        }
    }        
}
```

This outputs the following XML (notice no type info on Nullable Number and Number--this is the desired output):

```
<Test xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NullableNumber>7</NullableNumber>
  <Number>5</Number>
</Test>
```

If I modify the above code as follows (adding [Serializable], : ISerializable, and the two serialization methods):

```
[Serializable]
class Test : ISerializable
{
    public Test() { }
    public Nullable<int> NullableNumber = 7;
    public int Number = 5;

    public static void Go()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
        using (var s = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(s.BaseStream, test);
        }
    }        
    public Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        NullableNumber = info.GetInt32("NullableNumber");
        Number = info.GetInt32("Number");
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("NullableNumber", NullableNumber);
        info.AddValue("Number", Number);
    }
}
```

It now emits the following XML.  Notice the type information (i:type="x:int") added to each element.

```
<Test xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLSerialization" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NullableNumber i:type="x:int" xmlns="">7</NullableNumber>
  <Number i:type="x:int" xmlns="">5</Number>
</Test>
```

Why is it doing this?  How do I stop it from doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the question, because it solved my question :-) As for "why" -- in the first example there was a guarantee each entry is a field, so you can get the type of the field just by looking at `Test` type. In second case **you** are in control, so those entries do not have to be fields at all, you could be writing/reading just random data.

Comment: There is now a solution to this, available from .NET Framework 4.5. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you want full control over serialization to xml, you can use XmlSerializer

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Nullable<int> NullableNumber = 7;

    [XmlElement("NullableNumber")]
    public int NullableNumberValue
    {
        get { return NullableNumber.Value; }
        set { NullableNumber = value; }
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeNullableNumberValue()
    {
        return NullableNumber.HasValue;
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public int Number = 5;
}
```

sample serialization code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Test());
}
```

results:

```
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Number>5</Number>
  <NullableNumber>7</NullableNumber>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in .Net Framework 4.5 (and .Net Core 1.0), this is possible using the `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` class:

```
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
{
    EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never
};
var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test), settings);
```

The `EmitTypeInformation` settings tells the serializer not to output the (annoying?) `__type` parameter during serialization.

There are a range of other useful settings available.  [Here is the docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings) for `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `ISerializable` here? What was the regular `DataContractSerializer` not giving you? If you switch back to this, it should work fine.

Basically, by implementing custom serialization, the data is no longer contract based - so it *has* to include this extra information to guarantee that it is able to understand it later.

So: is there a reason to implement `ISerializable` in this case?

Comment: I trimmed down the example to make the question easier.  I need custom serialization for reasons I don't show here.

Comment: Of the (long list) of reasons I need custom serialization, the biggest is that I need to conditionally output certain properties based on other information.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "it 'has' to include this extra information".  Indeed, the first XML example above deserializes just fine with the [Serializable] deserializer, so the deserializer does not need this type info.