# How to serialize type derived from ConfigurationSection with NetDataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, configuration, netdatacontractserializer

I wrote my type derived from `ConfigurationSection` tagged all properties with `DataMember` and class with `DataContract`, however program crashes stating I cannot inherit my type from a type that is not marked with `DataContract`.

So how could I use this serializer with `ConfigurationSection`?

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class MyConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    [DataMember]
    [ConfigurationProperty("ConnectionTimeout", DefaultValue = 1000)]
    public int ConnectionTimeout
    {
        get { return (int)this["ConnectionTimeout"]; }
        set { this["ConnectionTimeout"] = value; }
    }
    ... // other values
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: @Übercoder, see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way -- instead of relying on automatic serialization, write your custom serialization manually. Since `NetDataContractSerializer` supports it, you can end up with just single type with 2 additional methods (more precisely: extra method for serializing and constructor for deserializing).

As for example see the post: [When using ISerializable with DataContractSerializer, how do I stop the serializer from outputting type information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710745/when-using-iserializable-with-datacontractserializer-how-do-i-stop-the-serializ#comment70746021_710745)

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess if you cant use the serializer with non data contract class than  maybe you should separate data member properties into another class which will aggregated in your ConfigurationSection:

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class CustomConfig
{
   [DataMember]
    public int ConnectionTimeout {get;set;}
}

public sealed class MyConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    private CustomConfig _customCfg = new  CustomConfig(){ConnectionTimeout = this.ConnectionTimeout};

    [ConfigurationProperty("ConnectionTimeout", DefaultValue = 1000)]
    public int ConnectionTimeout
    {
        get { return (int)this["ConnectionTimeout"]; }
        set { _customCfg.ConnectionTimeout = value;this["ConnectionTimeout"] = value; }
    }
    ... // other values
}
```

Than you can serialize CustomConfig instance with your serializer

Comment: For now I use something similar, I create wrapper type, that has exactly the same values, on creation this wrapper copies all the values from the `config` type. However those are implementation details, one fragile point is, you forget once about copying and you will have default value in the target type. So I am looking for something more automatic.

Comment: Maybe than use reflection to copy properties? Than if you'll add new properties they will be copied automatically.

Comment: Thank you, good idea. I wait a bit, if I won't find anything I will go this route (and accept your answer), ok?